# delete specific resource i.e, vm,nic,nsg using terraform

Tags: resources, terraform, devops, azure-virtual-machine, devops-services

I have created azure vm ,nic ,nsg inside the firewall. Now i need to delete specific created vm,nic,nsg inside the firewall. This i will be doing continuously.

When i try i delete with specific vm,ns,nic with below, but it is deleting total resource group.

```
terraform init
terraform apply -no-color -auto-approve
terraform destroy -force
```

My code:

```
# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
    subscription_id = "xxxxx"
    client_id       = "xxxxx"
    client_secret   = "xxxxx"
    tenant_id       = "xxxxx"
}

# Locate the existing custom/golden image
data "azurerm_image" "search" {
  name                = "AZLXSPTDEVOPS01_Image"
  resource_group_name = "RG-EASTUS-SPT-PLATFORM"
}

output "image_id" {
  value = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/RG-EASTUS-SPT-PLATFORM/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/AZLXSPTDEVOPS01_Image"
}

# Create a Resource Group for the new Virtual Machine.
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
  name     = "RG-PF-TEST"
  location = "eastus"
}

# Create a Subnet within the Virtual Network
resource "azurerm_subnet" "internal" {
  name                 = "SNET-IN"
  virtual_network_name = "VNET-PFSENSE-TEST"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
  address_prefix       = "192.168.2.0/24"
}

# Create a Network Security Group with some rules
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "main" {
  name                = "RG-Dev-NSG"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"

  security_rule {
    name                       = "allow_SSH"
    description                = "Allow SSH access"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "22"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
}

# Create a network interface for VMs and attach the PIP and the NSG
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
  name                      = "NIC-Dev"
  location                  = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"
  resource_group_name       = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
  network_security_group_id = "${azurerm_network_security_group.main.id}"

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "primary"
    subnet_id                     = "${azurerm_subnet.internal.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "static"
    private_ip_address            = "192.168.2.6"
  }
}

# Create a new Virtual Machine based on the Golden Image
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name                             = "AZLXSPTDEVOPS01"
  location                         = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"
  resource_group_name              = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
  network_interface_ids            = ["${azurerm_network_interface.main.id}"]
  vm_size                          = "Standard_DS12_v2"
  delete_os_disk_on_termination    = true
  delete_data_disks_on_termination = true

  storage_image_reference {
    id = "${data.azurerm_image.search.id}"
  }

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "AZLXSPTDEVOPS01-OS"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
}

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "APPVM"
    admin_username = "devopsadmin"
    admin_password = "admin#2019"
  }

  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }
}
```

I need to delete only specific vm,nic and nsg .Could anyone help me please

Comment: You probably want the `-target` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah Now Iam able to delete specific resource with below commands.

```
terraform init
terraform apply -no-color -auto-approve
terraform destroy -target azurerm_network_interface.main -no-color -auto-approve
terraform destroy -target azurerm_network_security_group.main -no-color -auto-approve
terraform destroy -target azurerm_virtual_machine.vm -no-color -auto-approve
```